# Displaying dart (leader) on Callout text symbol inserted into ArcGIS Pro Layout

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, callout

This procedure can be followed to see where I am stuck when trying to use the Callout (San Serif) text symbol of ArcGIS Pro:

1. Start ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0 and create a new Project using any Template (I used Map)
2. Insert a Layout using any page size
3. On the page use the Insert ribbon to click on the Symbol button in the Text group and in the gallery choose Callout (Sans Serif) from the Layout category
4. Use the Rectangle Text tool to drag out a rectangle for the callout text symbol
5. In the Element pane you should see Format Text as its heading, so switch to the Text Symbol tab and then to its Properties tab.  You should see something like this:

[image]

6. Under Appearance change the font Size to be 48 pt and then Apply.  You should see the sample text in the Element pane has a dart (leader) coming off from near its bottom left corner whereas the text on the layout does not:

[image]

How do I get the text element just created to have a dart leading off it too?

I suspect that it may be under Callout (see below) where the Dart Symbol has an Outline width of 0 pt but I have not been able to change that from being grayed out.  I have also tried ticking the Fixed Dart Width checkbox so that I can increase it from 7 pt to 100 pt as a test.  Neither helped.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this the Callout text element needs to be right-clicked on in the layout page (or by using its name in the Contents pane).

There is then an option on the Context Menu to Add Leader:

[image]

The Callout on the page then has the appearance and functionality that I was looking for:

[image]